# How to sort a python list, based on different indices?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, lambda

For instance, we have a list of list.
The list should be reverse sorted based on some index i, and if there is tie, they should be sorted in ascending or descending order based on the condition.

For eg:

The list is `[['A', 2, 4.2], ['B', 4, 4.5], ['C', 2, 3.3], ['D', 2, 3.5]]`

How to sort this so that the result is:

- `[['B', 4, 4.5], ['A', 2, 4.2], ['D', 2, 3.5], ['C', 2, 3.3]]`
- `[['B', 4, 4.5], ['C', 2, 3.3], ['D', 2, 3.5], ['A', 2, 4.2]]`

In first condition, i want them to be sorted in descending order based on `index 1`, and then again on descending order on `index 2` if there is tie on `index 1`.

In second condition, i want them to be sorted in descending order based on `index 1`, and then  in ascending order on `index 2` if there is tie on `index 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can think of is what follows:

```py
myList = [['A', 2, 4.2], ['B', 4, 4.5], ['C', 2, 3.3], ['D', 2, 3.5]]
print(sorted(myList, key= lambda x: (x[1], x[2]), reverse=True))
print(sorted(myList, key= lambda x: (x[1], -1*x[2]), reverse=True))
```

##### Output

```
[['B', 4, 4.5], ['A', 2, 4.2], ['D', 2, 3.5], ['C', 2, 3.3]]
[['B', 4, 4.5], ['C', 2, 3.3], ['D', 2, 3.5], ['A', 2, 4.2]]
```

##### Explnatation

`sorted` function takes two arguments: an iterable, which can be a list, set, or anything that is iterable, and a key, which defines the pattern of sorting. In the key argument, I have defined a tuple (`(x[1], x[2])`) that indicates the order of sorting, if the element with index 1 is tied, then it goes to check index number 2. The second sorted function is the same, but when it goes to the element with index number 2, it checks its negative value to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: It fails if I do `-1 * x[i]` for strings element in the list.

Comment: @HarshitBhat How do you want to sort the strings in the list? I mean. what is the pattern?

Comment: Like they appear in the dictionary.

Comment: @HarshitBhat For the strings, I suggest you use `ord` in order to convert the character (string) to a number. Something like: `-1 * ord[x[i]]`. Please, make sure that `x[i]` is a character.